# Pyinstaller standalone executable cannot find ui file defined in spec file

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I'm using pyinstaller to compile a standalone executable file. The python script uses an external ui file from QtDesigner. I don't get it to run the executable file without the ui file. I read about defining a spec file, but everything I tried doesn't work without the ui file. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I can compile it, but when I remove the ui file and run the executable I get the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:/visu.ui'
```

How can I integrate this file to the executable?

This is my code. The spec file was generated with pyi-makespec and added the data manually:

visu.py

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic

def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(resource_path('visu.ui'))

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

visu.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>172</width>
    <height>122</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>40</x>
     <y>50</y>
     <width>93</width>
     <height>28</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Ok</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

visu.spec

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['D:/visu.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\xxx'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[("visu.ui", '.')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='visu',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='visu')
```

Answer (score 0):

I know for sure that if you convert the `visu.ui` file to`visu.py`

```
pyuic5 visu.ui -o visu.py
```

then you will not have any problems.

```
pyinstaller -F -w pyinstaller_standalone_executable.py
```

**pyinstaller_standalone_executable.py**

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets     #, uic

from visu import Ui_Dialog

'''
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """

    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(resource_path('visu.ui'))
'''

#class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(
            lambda: QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None, "Message", self.pushButton.text())
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]